# going through exercise

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Myridon:
> "like a block, esp in shape and solidarity" is pretty funny as we're ***going through the exercise*** in this thread of showing that "block" isn't a shape.

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/anvil-a-heavy-iron-block-on-which.3931328/#post-20125217)

I'm not sure what "***going through the exercise***" means in that context.

Comment: It would be the same thing in your language. exercise of showing that "block" isn't a shape.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, but I'm having trouble understand the meaning of ***exercise***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, it means that we are **exercising** in this thread to show that "block" isn't a shape.

One of the meanings of "exercise" is this:

> use or apply (a faculty, right, or process)

> E.g. "control is exercised by the Board"

**exercising** in this sentence means that we are *practicing* or in the *process* of showing that "block" in fact is not a shape!